# What is the point of the URI specification?

Tags: specifications, uri

As far as I understand it, the URI specification says that URIs are strings of the format `scheme:b`, and the format of `b` is specified by `scheme` (and there is not a finite centralised list of what `scheme` nor thus the formats of `b` can be).

So what's the point of that? Why would you want the concept of URI to exist? Why is that more useful than just the `b` part itself? Every technology can deal with their own `b` parts.

Comment: [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986) seems a lot longer than what you describe to me.

Comment: The RFC has a lot of information, but I don't think there is a good short summary of *why* you would choose to use a URI versus some other means to identify something.

Comment: To provide a direct answer: the point of the URI specification is to provide a standardized way to create, parse, and interpret URIs... but I don't think that's your *true* question.

Comment: How do you know whether `theonlygusti` is a HTTP resource or an email address?

Comment: @JörgWMittag because of how I store it. It could be in a database column called "email" or one called "username", it could be passed to a function as the "email" parameter, etc.

Comment: @GregBurghardt My question is, why do URIs have to be specified at all? Why did someone think that standardising `something:`-prefixed strings was a great idea and why are URIs so ubiquitous?

Comment: I am not clear what the question is here, to put it another whats wrong with this specification I can't think of any problems having it causes?

Comment: The question makes sense to me - the OP is asking what value the existence of the specification provides, why people were motivated to write it and read it. I think it would be possible to give a good answer. Well known specifications don't generally exist for no reason.

Comment: @theonlygusti You put it in your database like that. Now how do you pass that scheme to the OS so it knows how to launch an app, that your system may not even know exists? For example, the zoom and ms teams apps, register themselves as a custom schema handler so they can launch any links to meetings with the app.

Comment: @user1937198 it would be in the database in the Microsoft Teams column, so you just call "open MS teams with this ..." I see now why your app may sometimes want to be scheme-agnostic tho, e.g. making a calendar app, include the Join Meeting link - it could be zoom or teams and you don't want your calendar app to have to have knowledge of every meeting client that exists and how to open it

Comment: That's like asking why have a file type/version header in a file format. What if you're writing software that supports multiple file types, or multiple versions of the same file type? You want a quick way to determine what you should be doing with the file. Similarly, what if you want to support multiple `scheme`s (either directly or by delegating to other software) - like your browser does *right now*? E.g., it does different things for `http:`, `https:`, `file:`, `ftp:`, `mailto:`, etc.

Answer (score 8):

URI's are designed to unambiguously identify a resource across different namespaces and addressing systems, like HTTP, FTP, NNTP, Gopher, email etc. Hence you need the scheme to indicate which addressing system is in use.

The idea was to connect various pre-existing information systems into a common hypertext universe. You could have a web page that had links to other web pages but also to text files hosted on FTP servers or newsgroup posts on NNTP servers.

URI's are designed to be independent of any particular file format. They should be usable in HTML as hyperlinks, but they should also be usable in plaintext, in other document formats (like Word documents), in emails, even on paper and posters.

You suggest in a comment that the scheme could be indicated through HTML attributes:

> `<email to="john@doe">` instead of `<a href="mailto:john@doe">`

This puts the scheme into the tag name rather than the URI itself, but it would only work in HTML. URI's are designed to work across different formats, even plaintext. So the scheme is made part of the URI itself.

Answer (score 4):

The scheme for a URI provides context and meaning for how you should interpret the URI, and ultimately request the resource being identified.

The "U" in URI means "Universal" — you should be able to interpret a URI the same way whether it was embedded in a web page, or written down on a napkin passed to you in a restaurant. The [href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#href) attribute of the `<a>` tag is a good real world example of why the scheme in a URI matters.

If the scheme is `http` or `https`, the web browser knows it can use the HTTP protocol to request that resource. If the scheme is `mailto`, the browser knows it should invoke the default mail client, passing the full URI. The default mail client knows that `mailto:someone@example.com` should spawn a window allowing the end user to compose an e-mail, and the part after the `:` is the e-mail address that should be inserted automatically into the "To" field.

The URI itself has no behavior. The scheme is used by an application to determine if the URI is something it can process. If not, then the application might delegate this to the operating system. The part after the `:` is interpreted by the application as something specific to that application.

This is why `http://example.com/contact.html` causes a web browser to establish a socket connection to the host at `example.com` on port 80. Upon connecting, the browser sends `HTTP/1.1 GET /contact.html` to the web server, and it knows when the server responds with `404 Not Found` that the browser should not attempt to request that resource again.

This is why `mailto:someone@example.com` causes your default mail client to open a "New Message" window and populate the "To" field with "someone@example.com". The application knows how to interpret that URI and do something specific with it.

Here is a fun little experiment for Microsoft Windows users.

1. Open Windows File Explorer.
2. Click on the location bar.
3. Type `mailto:someone@example.com` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you have a default e-mail client, I bet the mail client spawns a "New Message" window with "someone@example.com" pre-filled in the "To" field. Windows didn't do this. The Windows operating system has a catalog of which applications handle a particular URI scheme. When the operating system encounters a scheme it cannot handle, it will consult this catalog to see which application does handle that scheme. It will send a message or event to that application, and pass along the full URI. That's when your mail client recognizes the "mailto" scheme and opens a new message window.

Now try this:

1. Open the Windows command line.
2. Type `explorer 'https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/'` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I bet your default web browser opens up, bringing you back to this site.

Back in your command line, type `explorer 'mailto:someone@example.com'` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You get a new message window in your default mail client, don't you?

The reason to use a URI is to facilitate this flexible behavior without needing to pass instructions about how to interpret the URI. If an application can understand the URI, then great. Do something with it. If the application cannot handle a particular scheme, applications generally delegate to the operating system, where the operating system might know another application that can handle it.

Comment: Now go to your phone, and try sms:000555000 in the browser.

Comment: @user1937198, or in your browser type `'tel:0005550000'`.

Answer (score 2):

When someone hands you a bunch of ones and zeros it's nice if they tell you what to do with them.

In [windows](https://vtcri.kayako.com/article/296-view-file-extensions-windows-10), files do this in their names after the last dot: .exe, .txt

In linux, files do this with the first line of the file with the shebang: !bash

On the internet, addresses do this with a string before a colon: http, mailto, gopher

> and there is not a finite centralised list of what `scheme` nor thus the formats of `b` can be

And there never will be. Which is why anyone can add to it. Oh sure, some people keep a [list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml) but that doesn't put them in charge of this.

Anyone can tell you what to do with their ones and zeros. It's completely up to you if you want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be thinking about this from a very narrow viewpoint.  It's a bit like me asking what the point of a prosthetic leg is given that I have all the legs I need. If you have a database or some sort of storage that you control, of course you can keep track of what the context of the location is.  But that's not the point.  The point is so that when you share a location with someone else, they know how to interpret it.

The context of this is the web (really hypertext.)  Look at the page you are viewing this on.  There are many links on it.  They all happen to have the `scheme` of 'https' but they don't have to.  If you didn't have that as part of the URL, how would the browser know what type of link it was?  You would need to specify that somehow.  But you don't have to because it's already a solved problem.

Comment: When do you share a location with someone else without context? Why is it so desirable that all "locations" can be represented in a string as `typeoflocation:location`? About HTML, it could have had `<email to="john@doe">` instead of `<a href="mailto:john@doe">` for each type of "link" a website might want.

Comment: @theonlygusti "When do you share a location with someone else without context?" In HTML which is what the spec was created for as noted, in the answer.

Comment: When does a developer put an anchor tag on a webpage and not know what type of resource it will link to?

Comment: "About HTML, it could have had <email to="john@doe"> instead of <a href="mailto:john@doe"> for each type of "link" a website might want."  OK.  Why is that better in your mind?

Comment: "When does a developer put an anchor tag on a webpage and not know what type of resource it will link to?"  That makes no sense. It's not for the developer. It's for the client browser.

Comment: @theonlygusti tags works for html, but its not a general solution. What about command lines, clipboards, phone app interfaces, QR codes or sms messages? Uris provide a _uniform_ method of specifying how to interpret the location referenced.

Comment: Did you know you can create a QR code that will open up an SMS conversation on someones phone? Why, because QR codes contain URIs, and there is an SMS uri scheme.

Comment: That's better in my mind because: the behaviour of clicking the "link" is totally different depending on the scheme. I don't think "Send this in an email" buttons and "Next page" links really belong in the same conceptual category.

Comment: Also, the `href` accepts any gibberish, but the browser needs to know how to handle the schema to make it meaningful.  Why not just enumerate all the meaningful categories (which all have different behaviours too) as their own elements? To me, the current state seems analogous to using a programming language that has a type system, but choosing to pass stringified objects everywhere instead.

Comment: @user1937198 okay I see the benefit. I mean, QR codes could obviously encode the scheme and data their own way, but since so many applications need to do that, just standardise it. I was thrown off by learning that the URI specification specifies... so little.

Comment: @theonlygusti The browser doesn't necessarily. The browser only needs to know if its something it can handle. The browser can chose to reference an OS level database for how to handle it. So email gets handled by the users preferred client without the browser needing to care about what that is. Same for a zoom meeting.

Comment: @theonlygusti Your suggestion is simply respecifying the same amount of information in a different format; one that I would argue is worse because it is poorly suited for other types of situations.  There are many schemes that don't really need to be supported by browsers such as 's3'.

Comment: My thinking was that those that don't need to be supported by browsers don't need to adhere to the same specifications. Still feels like a non-specification to me tbh

Comment: Now there is an argument for specifying that a URI is two strings, a schema and a reference, but given that in so many places it needs to be passed through locations where only a single field is available, a standard encoding is useful.

Comment: @theonlygusti "The browser can chose to reference an OS level database for how to handle it."  How?  Here's a hyptotheical scheme-free link: 'foobar'.  How are you going to figure out what it is with your database?

Comment: @user1937198 I agree and see the point. But I guess if it had been two strings since the beginning, there would have been two fields in all cases too right?

Comment: @theonlygusti Now how do I put that through a text only clipboard?

Comment: @JimmyJames I was referencing things like `mailto` or `zoom` or `msteams`, where a standard implementation is to query the OS to find out what application is supposed to handle it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows gives an example of how windows provides this.

Comment: @user1937198 Sorry, I lost the thread it seems.  Never mind.